# Backbone UI Model binding with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm looking to implement UI binding in a Backbone application using handlebars.  I've put together a simple example to demonstrate the design pattern but I've noticed it is not going to scale very well because it requires rendering the entire template every time a model value is changed.

Is there a way to update individual values in a handlebars template instead of needing to re-render the entire template?

HTML:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="box {{#if active}} active {{/if}}">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <button class="btn" data-class="toggleActive">Toggle Active</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "Test",
        description: "This is a test description!",
        active: false
    }
});

var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html()),
    events: {
        "click [data-class='toggleActive']": "toggleActive"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.model = new TestModel();
        this.render();
        this.model.on("change", this.renderUI, this);

    },
    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        $('body').html(self.$el.html(self.template(self.model.toJSON())));
    },
    renderUI: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },
    toggleActive: function(){
        var isActive = this.model.get("active");
        this.model.set("active", !isActive);
    }
});

var testView = new TestView();
```

Comment: Angular updates the entire template every time and it's pretty popular. I'm afraid the question you are asking is very broad and there is not a correct solution, there are many ways to do and they are all pretty involved. A better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ? A possible solution: Each view needs to specify a CSS selector for each model property that is rendered in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view knows the selectors to each place that uses your element in template, you can do something like the following, which creates a separate handler for each property change and updates the related HTML using the selector you provided

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile($("#entry-template").html()),
    events: {
        "click [data-class='toggleActive']": "toggleActive"
    },
    modelBindings: {
      // property name: CSS selector of where to update
      title: 'h1',
      description: 'p'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.model = new TestModel();
        this.render();

        var me = this;

        function createHandler(selector) {
            return function(model, value) {
                me.$(selector).html(value);
            }                
        }

        for (var modelProp in this.modelBindings) {
            this.model.on("change:" + modelProp, createHandler(this.modelBindings[modelProp]));
        }

    },
    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        $('body').html(self.$el.html(self.template(self.model.toJSON())));
    },

    toggleActive: function(){
        var isActive = this.model.get("active");
        this.model.set("active", !isActive);
    }
});
```

This only works for places where you want to update the HTML, and it won't work in the case where you want the class to be added. In that case, you could use the same concept that would add/remove attributes to an element

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to particular attribute changes on your model and only update the corresponding html element.

listen to model title change (`this.listenTo` is the same as `this.on` but it allows listeners to be unbound when calling `this.stopListening`).

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:title', this.updateTitle);
```

Then create the `updateTitle` handler.

```
updateTitle: function(model, value, options)
{
    // this.$ === this.$el.find
    this.$('h1').text(value);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP would like an automatic way of updating the places that say `{{someModelProperty}}`

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah you could be right, however this does solve the OPs issue of not wanting to re-render the entire template.

Comment: I've created a [more generic version of your method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25515139/227299)

Comment: I feel like using jQuery to update each instance of data in the template defeats the purpose of using handlebars in the first place.

If your establishing a reference to every dom object that holds dynamic data in your view why not exclude handlbars all together?

I guess I don't understand the point of a templating language if you cant use it to change values in the template...